Adding Annotations to Categorical X-Axis in Plotly
Working in plotly.express and plotly graph_objects and I am trying to add arrows to denote the movement from one data point to another. Both points share a categorical x-axis (serial number).
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px
import plotly.graph_objects as po

df = pd.DataFrame([['1600',255,110],['1832',235,92],['1732',210,200]])
df.columns = ['SN','MetA','MetB']
df = df.sort_values('SN')
df.reset_index(drop = True,inplace = True)
scat = px.scatter(df, x = 'SN', y = ['MetA','MetB'])

list_of_all_arrows = []

for i in df.index:
    arrow = go.layout.Annotation(dict(
                    x=i
                    y=df.loc[i,'MetA']
                    xref="x", yref="y",
                    text="",
                    showarrow=True,
                    axref="x", ayref='y',
                    ax=i
                    ay=df.loc[i,'MetB'],
                    arrowhead=3,
                    arrowwidth=1.5,
                    arrowcolor='rgb(255,51,0)',)
                )
    list_of_all_arrows.append(arrow) 

scat.update_layout(annotations = list_of_all_arrows)

pio.show(scat)

So this works and creates the following picture as I would expect
annotated arrows working properly
However, when running the same code on a larger dataset, this happens:
misaligned arrows
Any ideas? I have to plot as strings on the X-axis.

figured it out on my own
apparently plotly doesn't guarantee the order of categorical data on the x-axis (seems dumb but w/e)
scat.update_xaxes(categoryorder = 'category ascending')

